# Devise, OmniAuth and Google Apps "Connected Sites, Apps and Services" name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, google-apps

I am using Devise with OmniAuth+OpenID to authenticate users against our Google Apps domain. 
However, when I go into Account -> Security -> Connected Applications and Sites", my application shows up as

`localhost — Sign in using your Google account`

My OmniAuth is configured like this:

`config.omniauth :google_apps, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :domain => 'domain.com'`

Where can I set the application name, so users are aware what exactly they are authenticating?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the open-id gem is just a quick and dirty way to get some authentication using a Gmail account. Since you don't register an app, you can't customize the authentication prompt, like choosing a name, a description and a logo of your application.

To do that, you should register your app at [Google's Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console), get your API key and secret and use them with the [omniauth-google-oauth2 gem](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2).

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your answer. I actually tried using OAuth2 instead of OpenID before, however, that opens my application to pretty much anyone with gmail account. There is a post here mentioning use of `hd=domain.com` parameter, but that did not work for me, plus I still had to do validation for a correct domain on my end, so i went with OpenID gem instead.

Comment: Now that Google closed OpenID (https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable), I'm in the same situation (finding a solution to use OAuth2 with a Google Apps domain). Did you manage to make the `hd` parameter to work at some point? thanks!